# Exception has occurred: KeyError (numpy list)

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, mnist

I am trying to get the list of my class labels as shown below:

```
train_data=pd.read_csv(r'D:\MachinLearning\MyDataSets_Implementations\SVM\mnist_train.csv')

order = list(np.sort(train_data['label'].unique()))
print(order)
```

but an error appears with "Exception has occurred: KeyError" title then, it opens the 'Hashtable_class_helper.pxi' file.

How should I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the dataframe has a column with that name?

Comment: The problem was exactly the Column name. As you mentioned, there was no column name at my dataset and i didn't carefully check it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Which version of numpy are you using?